# Click on Button doesn't drill down items in Table Bootstrap 4 and JS and JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a list with items they have a status assigned (5 + 1 to show all items), the status is in a specific column, and for each of the status  i have a button above the list.

Now i wanna click on one of each button to drill down the list in order to show only the items with the status i have clicked on that button. I have 5 buttons for each status 1 button, plus 1 button called total which is supposed to show all data again.

I use Bootstrap 4 and Javascript, but can't really get around the JS.

Below is my code snippet.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  resStatusList();
  $(".searchGo").click(function() {
    var searchVal = $('#searchTotal').val();
    if (searchVal == "") {
      $('#searchroleName').addClass("alert");
    } else {
      $('#searchroleName').removeClass("alert");
    }
  });

  var $rows = $('#resListTable tr');
  $('#searchroleName').keyup(function() {
    var val = $.trim($(this).val()).replace(/ +/g, ' ').toLowerCase();
    $rows.show().filter(function() {
      var text = $(this).text().replace(/\s+/g, ' ').toLowerCase();
      return !~text.indexOf(val);
    }).hide();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="addRoleDiv">
  <h4>Reservation List</h4>
  <label>click on a button to drill down items</label><br>
  <button class="btn searchGo btn-active" id="searchTotal">Total</button>
  <button class="btn searchGo btn-success" id="searchExpected">Expected</button>
  <button class="btn searchGo btn-danger" id="searchCancelled">Cancelled</button>
  <button class="btn searchGo btn-warning" id="searchPartial">Partial</button>
  <button class="btn searchGo btn-info" id="searchInhouse">Inhouse</button>
  <button class="btn searchGo btn-active" id="searchFinished">Finished</button>
</div>

<div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-xs-12 padding table-responsive">
  
  <table class="table table-hover table-bordered" id="reservationListCheckIn">
    <thead class="reservationTableHead">
      <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Status</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="resListTable">
    <tr>
    <td>864</td>
    <td>Helen Fields</td>
    <td>Expected</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>2435</td>
    <td>Frank White</td>
    <td>Cancelled</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>2343</td>
    <td>Hugo Egon</td>
    <td>Inhouse</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>245</td>
    <td>Marc Jacobs</td>
    <td>Partial</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>43</td>
    <td>Julia Kline</td>
    <td>Finished</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

On *.searchGo* click you need to get current button text. If it is not "Total" you can hide all rows and show only the ones having the expected value in the last column:

```
$('#reservationListCheckIn tbody tr').hide();
$('#reservationListCheckIn tbody tr td:nth-of-type(3)').filter(function(idx, ele) {
    return ele.textContent == titleBtnClicked;
}).closest('tr').show();
```

For details you can see:

- [:nth-of-type() Selector](https://api.jquery.com/nth-of-type-selector/) : Selects all elements that are the nth child of their parent in relation to siblings with the same element name.
- [.filter( function )](http://api.jquery.com/filter/#filter-function):  Reduce the set of matched elements to those that match the selector or pass the function's test.

The snippet:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".searchGo").on('click', function(e) {

        // get current button text
        var titleBtnClicked = $(this).text();

        // if not Total
        if (titleBtnClicked != 'Total') {

            // hide all rows
            $('#reservationListCheckIn tbody tr').hide();

            // show only rows having in the 3th cell the correct value
            $('#reservationListCheckIn tbody tr td:nth-of-type(3)').filter(function(idx, ele) {
                return ele.textContent == titleBtnClicked;
            }).closest('tr').show();
        } else {
            $('#reservationListCheckIn tbody tr').show();
        }
    });

});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://rawgit.com/HubSpot/tether/master/dist/css/tether.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="addRoleDiv">
    <h4>Reservation List</h4>
    <label>click on a button to drill down items</label><br>
    <button class="btn searchGo btn-active" id="searchTotal">Total</button>
    <button class="btn searchGo btn-success" id="searchExpected">Expected</button>
    <button class="btn searchGo btn-danger" id="searchCancelled">Cancelled</button>
    <button class="btn searchGo btn-warning" id="searchPartial">Partial</button>
    <button class="btn searchGo btn-info" id="searchInhouse">Inhouse</button>
    <button class="btn searchGo btn-active" id="searchFinished">Finished</button>
</div>

<div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-xs-12 padding table-responsive">

    <table id="reservationListCheckIn" class="table table-hover table-bordered">
        <thead class="reservationTableHead">
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Status</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="resListTable">
        <tr>
            <td>864</td>
            <td>Helen Fields</td>
            <td>Expected</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>2435</td>
            <td>Frank White</td>
            <td>Cancelled</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>2343</td>
            <td>Hugo Egon</td>
            <td>Inhouse</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>245</td>
            <td>Marc Jacobs</td>
            <td>Partial</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>43</td>
            <td>Julia Kline</td>
            <td>Finished</td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

</div>
```

Comment: i have 2 tables on the same page, how can i apply the above only to table with **id="reservationListCheckIn"** ?

Comment: @Chris Instead of using $('.table tbody tr') you can use $('#reservationListCheckIn tbody tr').  Answer and snippet updated.

Comment: Hi @gaetanoM, unfortunately it isn't working in my environment. I have updated my code to the snippet. It might be a small piece.. :-/ Could you take a look?

Comment: @Chris Yes, I took a look and my js piece of code works. I don't know what I can say you. Please, see the differences between my snippet and your code. Is my snippet working? If yes, ....

Comment: @Chris **$('#reservationListCheckIn tbody tr')**  selects only the table with **id="reservationListCheckIn"** This for your first comment.